# automatically restart meteor when the settings change

Tags: meteor, gulp, restart

In development mode I start (a bit simplified) my meteor application as follows

```
$> meteor --settings=settings.json
```

Now I want meteor to restart when the content of `settings.json` changes. I'm using `gulp` to automate many things in my project, and it would be nice if gulp could somehow start and stop meteor too, so the new settings can be applied. Is this somehow possible with gulp or maybe an other method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor restarts when it detects that the settings file has been changed.

So theres no action required on your end.

Comment: My bad, I have too many settings files (outside the meteor directory) and I was using the wrong one :)